# Page numbering not working perfectly

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm having trouble with page numbering.
I wanted to get page numbering in right corner like this:
[image: pic]
In every page it is exactly as I want it to be, but in first page it is only as "1" not "1/4" and it is in center of footer and it doesn't have long line above it. How to get first page to show as in other pages?

I use this codes in it:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add a compilable document and not just fragments

Comment: Does the first page contain `\maketitle` or similar?

Comment: @samcarter yes it has right after /begin{document}

Comment: @RedRose: samcarters comment was the key to the problem here. The titlepage uses a `plain` as pagestyle. You could cure your problem with `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyfoot....}` like above

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good deduction Mr. Holmes!

Comment: @samcarter: Elementary, Mrs. Watson ;-) (but you had the first idea!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If the question would have include `\begin{document}` etc.  I would have saved these 50 sec your comments was faster ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'm using very first time LaTeX for my math project, so I'm new in this and did't really know what part of codes to include in Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353738/page-numbering-not-working-perfectly/353739#comment869795_353738) wrote in his comment, `\maketitle` changes the page style for the page it is on. To "repair" this, you can use `\thispagestyle{fancy}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}

\title{test}
\author{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```